# Why am i getting 'is not function' on calling sendRequest of the child components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently writing a small web-app in react and since it's my first time effectively using javascript i'm encountering some weird problems. I have a class `A` that should forward some behavior to its child components, but for whatever reason the child components methods can't be found an i receive the `is not a function` error.

Here the code:

`A.jsx`:

```
class A extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            type:""
        };
        this.foo = this.foo.bind(this);
        this.b = <B onClick={() => this.setState({type: "b"})}/>;
        this.c = <C onClick={() => this.setState({type: "c"})}/>;
    }

    render(){
        return (
        <SomeExternalStuff 
            sendRequest={this.foo}
            //some props...>
            {this.b}
            {this.c}
        </SomeExternalStuff>
        );
    }

    foo( test ){
        console.log(this.deletionButton);

        switch(this.state.type){
            case "b":
                this.b.bar(test);
                break;
            case "c":
                this.c.bar(test);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

`B.jsx`:

```
class B extends React.Component{
    static TITLE = "<some title>";

    render(){
        return (
            <Button type="submit" variant="danger" onClick={this.props.onClick}>
                {B.TITLE}
            </Button>
        );
    }

    bar(test){
        console.log("I'M IN B");
    }
}
```

`C.jsx` is nearly the same as `B.jsx`. I get the same error for both components.

Comment: It is because the name of the prop was `sendRequest` 
as ```sendRequest={this.sendRequest}```
,but you are using `onClick` in B component, which is not defined in the parent component

Comment: I would recommend you not to name another variable or function on the name of a prop.This will only increase confusion in your components.

Comment: I changed my question, and as far as i understood your reply this should solve the problem, but unfortunately it doesn't :/

Comment: just as a side note
https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly

Comment: Change `onClick` prop usage (which its predefeined js method)  to `handleClick` or something like that

Comment: I don't get where have you defined the `onClick` prop? That must be `this,props.sendRequest` instead of `this.props.onClick`

Comment: @RajatVerma I pass the props where i initialise the <B> and the <C> tag in the constructor

Comment: Maybe this will help [Call child method from parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37949981/call-child-method-from-parent)